# React Native - Rendering after pushing to array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm mapping an array to be rendered in React Native. On an event (button press) I want to add and object to the array and it be rendered on the screen. I am getting the lifecycle functions to trigger, but not sure if they are needed for this or how to utilize them effectively. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: '',
      text: '',
      submitted: false,
      count: 1,
      arr: [
        {
          key: 1,
          text: "text1"
       },
     ],
   }

buttonsListArr = this.state.arr.map(info => {
  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text key={info.key}>{info.text}</Text>
    <Button title='Touch' onPress={() => {
        this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
     }}/>
 </View> )
})

}

shouldComponentUpdate = () => {
    return true;
}

componentWillUpdate = () => {
    this.state.arr.push({key: this.state.count, text: 'text2'})
}

render() {

  return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    {buttonsListArr}

  </View>

  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've written is not typical. A quick fix is to move the logic to a render function like

```
constructor(props) {
.
.
    this.renderText = this.renderText.bind(this)
}

renderText() {
    return this.state.arr.map(info => {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <Text key={info.key}>{info.text}</Text>
                <Button title='Touch' onPress={() => {
                    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1})
                }}/>
            </View> )
    })
}
```

then call the function within the render()

```
render() {

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          {this.renderText()}

      </View>

   )
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using a lifecycle call to add an element to an array. Simply call setState and it will rerender itself!

Try this.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text key={info.key}>{info.text}</Text>
    <Button title='Touch' onPress={() => {
        this.setState({
            count: this.state.count + 1
            arr: this.state.arr.push({key: this.state.count, text: 'text2'})
        })
     }}/>
 </View> )
```

Comment: yeah I originally had that, it also doesn't update the screen on the onPress event

Comment: Have you tried exporting the function? like OnButtonPress = () => ....
and call that on the onPress in the function? don't forget the .bind(this) though. I have a feeling this might have to do with "this" being different in the map function.

If that doesn't work take a look at ListView: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html

Comment: I fixed that and added the comma after the count statement, still doesn't render, an error is thrown on this.state.arr.push I believe because this.state is treated as immutable in this situation

Comment: I'll check that out also

Comment: used your suggestion, doesnt change anything

Answer (score 0):

return this.arrayholder.map(image => {
  return (

```
<View style={styles.ImageContainer}>

<Image style={styles.ImageContainer} source={image} />
  </View>

  )
```

})